# Create tsData with specific ARIMA coefficients

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, descriptive-statistics

Suppose for a time series, the arima output is:

```
Series: tsData
ARIMA(0,1,3) with drift 

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2     ma3    drift
      -0.8970  -0.3765  0.5342  -0.8579
s.e.   0.2025   0.2576  0.2041   0.1107

sigma^2 estimated as 5.751:  log likelihood=-63.23
AIC=136.47   AICc=139.19   BIC=143.13
```

I would like to create a tsData with the same coefficients ma1, ma2 and ma3 but changing de drift value to -0.6156 starting with ts value 73, with a periodicity of 1 and a total of 28 periods.

Does anybody know how to deal with this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a generalized ARIMA data simulator that is freely available to answer your problem. You have a couple of choices here

1) you could write your own data simulator , converting sets of uniform draws to normally distributed realizations (the error process) and then create a linear compound using your pre-specified arima model (the Y's). Throw away initial values to avoid startup assumptions and then normalize to get your beginning value.

or

2) use commercial software to do this  . I am aware that AUTOBOX ( a package that I helped to develop ) has such a feature. You could also contact SAS and SPSS to inquire about their capabilities in this regard.

Comment: Isn't there any easier way to solve the problem? I had thought about writing in r the arima equation like this

=(?−?)∗?+?−1−?−2+

However I don't know enough mathematics to write the function and clear the variable for the model I asked.

Comment: The X's are a linear function of the e's Not previous X's as your model is a pure MA . You could restate your MA model a pure AR model vut that would not be finite.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will use AUTOBOX then. Any instruction to do it with that program??

Comment: It's unnecessary to write your own simulator: base `r` includes `arima.sim` to do that.

Comment: that's great as I said i was unaware of such an offering

Comment: One correction your model is a hybrid of previous values via the differencing operator and the 3 coefficients on the error

Comment: So whuber I think that the only question that rests is how can I add de drift coeff to the arima.sim function.